# Spring boot , include one-to-many relation in Json response from both sides

Tags: java, spring-boot, one-to-many, bidirectional

I have two entities , product and category with a relation of oneToMany .
Each product have one category and a cagetory can have multiple products .

I can show the list of products in the JsonResponse from the category side but
not from the product side .
What I'm I missing ?

-JsonResponse when using Getting a category by categoryName :

- URL :http://localhost:8080/api/categories/electornique

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "reference": "cat1",
   "name": "electornique",
   "produits": [
      {
         "id": 2,
         "reference": "tab1",
         "designation": "ordinateurupdate",
         "price": 600,
         "quantite": 1234
      },
      {
         "id": 3,
         "reference": "tel1",
         "designation": "tel 1 was updated",
         "price": 600,
         "quantite": 1234
      },
      {
         "id": 4,
         "reference": "ord2",
         "designation": "ordinateur",
         "price": 400,
         "quantite": 3
      }
   ]
}
```

JsonResponse when using Getting a product by productReference :

URL : http://localhost:8080/api/produits/ord2

```
{
   "id": 4,
   "reference": "ord2",
   "designation": "ordinateur",
   "price": 400,
   "quantite": 3
}
```

I want to acheive this :

```
{
   "id": 4,
   "reference": "ord2",
   "designation": "ordinateur",
   "price": 400,
   "quantite": 3,
   categorie : { id : "" , reference : "", name: "" }
}
```

-Category entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categorie",indexes = {@Index (name="index_categorie_reference",columnList="reference",unique= true),
                                   @Index(name="index_categorie_name",columnList="name",unique= true)

})

public class Categorie implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String reference;

    @Column(unique= true)
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy= "categorie")
    private List<Produit> produits;


// getters and setters...    

}
```

-Product entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="produit",indexes = {@Index (name="index_produit_reference",columnList="reference",unique= true)})
public class Produit  implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String reference;

  private String designation;
  private double price;
  private int quantite;



  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="categorie_id") 
  @JsonIgnore
  private Categorie categorie;


  public Produit() {

  }


// getters and setters...   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see the `categorie` property because it's annotated with `@JsonIgnore`.

But if you remove that annotation, you will get an infinite loop when serializing your object...
[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) is a good article about the possible solutions/workarounds.

Comment: Yes i have followed this article,  it only gives solution from  one side of the relation not the two sides. My objective is being able to access catégorie from produit and produit from catégorie