# Stackoverflow when saving parent entity with child entity in Sprint Boot Rest Controller

Tags: spring-boot, rest, one-to-many

What I'd like to happen is when I hit `http://localhost:8080/accounts` with this payload:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "name": "sub",
            "phoneNumber": "0000000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd get:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "sub",
            "phoneNumber": "0000000000",
            "account": 1
        }
    ],
    "callServices": true
}
```

This is my Account class:

```
@Entity
class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null

    @Column
    lateinit var name: String

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
    lateinit var contacts: Set<Contact>

    @Column
    var callServices: Boolean = true
}
```

And my Contact class:

```
@Entity
class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null

    @Column
    lateinit var name: String

    @Column
    lateinit var phoneNumber: String

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    var account: Account? = null
}
```

When I try to create an account through this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("accounts")
class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var accountRepository: AccountRepository

    @PostMapping(produces = ["application/json"])
    fun createAccount(@RequestBody account: Account): Account {
        account.contacts.forEach { c -> c.account = account }
        return accountRepository.save(account)
    }
}
```

I get a Stackoverflow where looks like there some sort of circular dependency between account and contact. What am I missing here? Is `account.contacts.forEach` somehow trying to save to Hibernate and is that causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's going on here is that the account is being serialized as JSON and then the contacts within that object are getting serialized as JSON. The serializer then sees another Account object within one of the Contact objects and tries to serialize that (and then the cycle repeats with the serializer trying to serialize the Contact object within that Account object, etc).

Like in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58582304/1456621), using @JsonIgnore on the account object in Contact stops this process, and [here's an article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) that explains what's happening from Baeldung.